# bash program to copy all files from one location to another

Tags: bash, file, terminal

I am trying to write a simple bash program to execute on my terminal that will copy all of the files in one directory to another. This is my first bash program. This is what I have right now:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/georgi/Loopback_projects/ESPC/common/models
for f in *.json
do
cp -v $f /Users/georgi/AndroidStudioProjects/ESPC_Retrofit/app/src/main/assets
done
```

When I run the script in the terminal like that:

```
Chriss-iMac:georgi$ exportToAndroid.sh
```

it says `-bash: exportToAndroid.sh: command not found`

Comment: It looks fine to me, but why make a script for something this specific, not to mention trivial? You could easily do this in a one line command manually.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Robert when trying to run the script in the terminal it says "-bash: exportToAndroid.sh: command not found"

Comment: You need to make it executable with `chmod +x exportToAndroid.sh` and run it as `./exportToAndroid.sh`. But this is not really a Bash question.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you so much! That worked! Coupld you add that as an answer

Comment: You need to learn a little bit more about what your shell does when you enter stuff into it `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf. I intend to do that, yes :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

1. Make your script executable with:

   ```
   chmod +x exportToAndroid.sh
   ```
2. Run it with:

   ```
   ./exportToAndroid.sh
   ```

---

Long answer:

When you enter stuff in your terminal, the string is parsed, chopped into words, and (except for redirections or environmental variables or other keywords) the first word is understood as the command to be executed. If the shell recognizes this word as a function or a builtin (I'm ignoring aliases here) then it runs this function or builtin with the given arguments; but we're not in this case: `exportToAndroid.sh` is neither. In this case (since this word doesn't contain slashes), the shell will look into your `PATH` variable to check if it finds a file called `exportToAndroid.sh` (and if it finds it, it happily executes it); but here it isn't found! (check what your `PATH` variable contains with `echo "$PATH"`).

If instead of giving a slashless word you give a path with slashes, then the shell will not look into the `PATH` variable but will try to directly execute the file given. That's why

```
./exportToAndroid.sh
```

will work.

---

If you don't want to type `./` in front each time, here's a nice thing to do:

1. create in your home folder a `bin/` directory with

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ```
2. add this directory to your `PATH` variable like so: at the end of your `.bashrc` file, add the line `PATH=~/bin:$PATH` (well, this is not a robust way to prepend `~/bin` to your `PATH` variable, but it should be ok),
3. move your script to the `~/bin` folder,
4. restart your Bash session; you can check that your `~/bin` folder appears at the first position of your `PATH` variable with `echo "$PATH"`,
5. after a few months, you'll realize that your `bin/` folder contains lots of useless stuff you completely forgot about!

The nice thing about this is that you call your script with just `exportToAndroid.sh` from within whatever directory!

---

Comments about your code:

- In a script, after you `cd`, you should *always* check that the `cd` succeeds! one possibility:

  ```
  cd /Users/georgi/Loopback_projects/ESPC/common/models || { echo "Can't cd"; exit 1; }
  ```
- When using variable expansions, unless you really want word splitting and filename expansion to take place (and you very rarely want that! in fact, it's so uncommon practice, that when we want this to happen we always write a line of comment to explain our intent), *you must quote the expansion:* your `cp` line would be better written as

  ```
  cp -v "$f" /Users/georgi/AndroidStudioProjects/ESPC_Retrofit/app/src/main/assets
  ```

  (see the quotes?).
- When using a glob, as in `for f in *.json`, you should make sure that you have `shopt -s nullglob` (or `shopt -s failglob`) enabled.

At this point, your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

cd /Users/georgi/Loopback_projects/ESPC/common/models || { echo "Can't cd"; exit 1; }

for f in *.json; do
    cp -v "$f" /Users/georgi/AndroidStudioProjects/ESPC_Retrofit/app/src/main/assets
done
```

But in fact, a simpler and more efficient way would be to just do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s failglob

sourcedir=/Users/georgi/Loopback_projects/ESPC/common/models
targetdir=/Users/georgi/AndroidStudioProjects/ESPC_Retrofit/app/src/main/assets

cp -v "$sourcedir"/*.json "$targetdir"
```

It's much more efficient since we're only calling `cp` once, instead of *once per file to copy.*

Yet, this would fail if there are too many files to copy... but it will work with reasonably sized directories.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer! Much appreciated! :)